# Parallel transport in curved geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

This is sort of a very introductory question and I am not finding any reference regarding this. And let me know whether my answer is correct or not.

For example, we are parallelly transporting a vector on a surface (intrinsic parallel transport). We take two points and join by a curve and we will do the procedure along the curve. In terms of intrinsic coordinates $P=P(u)$ and $Q=Q(u+du)$. From $P(u)$ if we transport a vector, parallelly, the important condition is
$$
\nabla_i V^j=0\\
\text{or}, \quad \partial_iV^j=-\Gamma^j_{ik}V^k\\
\text{or,} \quad V_\parallel^j(u+du)=V_\parallel^j(u)-\Gamma^j_{ik}V_\parallel^k(u) du^i+\mathcal{O}(du^2)
$$
This transport is done in one path. If we take another path to do the same operation, if $R^a_{bcd} \neq 0$, we will get two different answers for the transported vector component at $Q(u+du)$. So, from the eqn how to interpret this? In particular, there should be some terms which will make $V_\parallel^j(u+du)$ different from one path to another.

Note: These changed $V_\parallel^j(u+du)$ will not make the vector from the point of view of the surface different, since the basis vector also have derivative and have $\Gamma$'s which can cancel the contributions from these $du^n$ terms.

One soln I was thinking, if we take a normal coordinate, for instance, $\Gamma$'s will vanish but $\partial \Gamma$'s will not vanish, hence they actually carry the information of curvature of the manifold. Hence to see actually $V_\parallel^j(u+du)$ are different at different paths, we have to expand upto $(du)^2$ at least.